# Find out type with primary key given in Entity Framework using TPH

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, tph

I have the following scenario:

```
public abstract class Account
{
    public Guid PKey { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();    
    public string Owner { get; set; }
}

public class CheckingAccount : Account
{
    public int Fee { get; set; }
}

public class SavingAccount : Account
{
    public double InterestRate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework with [Table per Hierarchy](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph), so that there will be a single table in the database that holds both *CheckingAccount*-Records and *SavingAccount*-Records and this table will contain a column named *Discriminator*, which is filled with the value "CheckingAccount" or "SavingAccount" respectively.

Now I want to take a primary key (Guid) as my input and find out the type of the record this primary key belongs to.

I have a given Guid and want to find out if the record for this Guid is a CheckingAccount-Record or a SavingAccount-Record.

I tried something like this:

```
using(MyContext ctx = new Context())
{
    CheckingAccount ca = ctx.CheckingAccount.Find(pKey);
    SavingAccount sa = ctx.SavingAccount.Find(pKey);

    if(ca != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a CheckingAccount!");
    }
    else if(sa != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a SavingAccount!");
    }
}
```

However, this results in an InvalidOperationException: When the record is a SavingAccount, it will say

> "The entity found was of type SavingAccount when an entity of type CheckingAccount was requested."

when I call the first Find() method.

How can I find out the type given only the primary key and the two types that it could belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use EF polymorphic queries through base entity `DbSet`. Something like this should do the job:

```
var account = ctx.Set<Account>().Find(pKey);
if(account is CheckingAccount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's a CheckingAccount!");
}
else if (account is SavingAccount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("It's a SavingAccount!");
}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thank You! Unfortunately, my upvote is not visible, since my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `var` or `object` as the type for `ca` and `sa`?

Give this a try:

```
using(MyContext ctx = new Context())
{
    object ca = ctx.CheckingAccount.Find(pKey);
    object sa = ctx.SavingAccount.Find(pKey);

    if(ca is CheckingAccount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a CheckingAccount!");
    }
    else if(sa is SavingAccount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("It's a SavingAccount!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work either. The Find()-Method itself throws the exception, even before assigning the result to a variable.

Comment: Do these types come from different sql tables?

Comment: No, all records are stored in a single table named "Account". The table contains a column named "Discriminator". In this column, the name of the type ("CheckingAccount" or "SavingAccount") is stored automatically when saving new records.